Motor Kv varying with load
I'm confused about the physical principle behind why a motor datasheet I found would list different Kv values for different load conditions. My understanding is that the induced emf in the stator windings should be proportional to rotor rotational frequency since that is proportional to the magnetic flux change they experience (for a PMSM). So why would a manufacturer list different Kv values for different load conditions for a PMSM? Especially since they only list one Kt value?

Please link to the motor datasheet or post a facsimile.

The Back EMF is indeed proportional to rotor rotational frequency, and a spinning motor will turn at the speed when the back EMF matches the implied motor voltage.  To determine the implied voltage, you must subtract the losses (primarily from motor winding resistance).  So, at higher torques, you can generally multiply the current times the winding phase resistance and subtract this from the applied voltage and, using this value instead of the applied voltage, Ke will be pretty constant.
The torque-current relationship holds in all cases.
Good question though!

So this higher implied voltage at load is mostly due to winding and core losses? Could this cause the "motor constant" to deviate by a large percentage (almost 40 - 50%)?

Yes.  If you measure the winding resistance you can do the math and I bet you come close.  Most motors list "Kv" or "Ke" by using the back EMF; if you spin the motor shaft and measure the voltage on the phases there is no current, so these losses are not present.  Many designers don't realize that these two constants (Ke and Kt) are actually the same number, expressed with different units.
